# Showing an expectation exists and is finite

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $X_1, X_2,…$ be iid sequence such that $P(X\in[m,M])=1$ for some $0<m<M<\infty$

How do I show that $E\big(\frac{X_2}{X_1}\big)$ exists and is finite?

Am I just using strong law of large numbers and just stating $X_1\rightarrow \mu_1$ And $X_2\rightarrow\mu_2$, where $\mu_1$ & $\mu_2$ are greater than $0$ and finite since $X\in [m,M]$, so they both must be finite and non-zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X_i \in [m,M]$ with probability $1$, it follows that $\frac{X_2}{X_{1}} \in \left[ \frac{m}{M}, \frac{M}{m}\right]$ with probability $1$. That means $\frac{X_2}{X_{1}}$ is a bounded random variable, which in turn implies it has finite expectation.